# Avoiding having to write several print calls python

Tags: python

I wrote a really short program but I hate having so many repetitive print calls that makes it seem as if a two year old coded my program.

```
userInput %= 6  
print (userInput)
userInput += userInput 
print (userInput)
userInput -= 4 
print (userInput)
userInput += 1 
print (userInput)
userInput *= 9.857143 
print (userInput)
userInput = str(userInput)
print ("<" + userInput + ">")
```

you can see how repetitive and ugly it is, I tried searching up and tried several things but they dont really work with what Im trying to do here.

Comment: You could save all the calculations in a list, then either iterate or join the list and print it.

Comment: It looks like those print statements are just for debugging, so that you can have some feedback that the value is changing the way you think it is. If that's the case, just use a REPL like the Python CLI or Jupyter Notebook, or use a debugger to inspect the values of all variables as you step through your code. Then no print statements are needed and your code stays clean

Answer (score 0):

Could just write a basic function, or if you don't want anyone to see your code, you could create a class and reference it instead. You would just create a new file, paste the class code into it, save it as userinput, then run UserInputter(somevaluehere) in the main code file. Doesn't really get rid of the problem, but prevents others from seeing your print statements unless they look at the class code.

```html
class UserInputter:

    def __init__(self,userInput):
        userInput %= 6  
        print (userInput)
        userInput += userInput 
        print (userInput)
        userInput -= 4 
        print (userInput)
        userInput += 1 
        print (userInput)
        userInput *= 9.857143 
        print (userInput)
        userInput = str(userInput)
        print ("<" + userInput + ">")
```

```html
from userinput import UserInputter
UserInputter(somevalue)
```

Comment: I don' tthink OP is trying to "hide" anything from others, just to keep the code clean

Comment: Not sure specifically what he's asking for, if he just wants to clean it up then either of the commented answers should be sufficient, figured I'd include this incase he just doesn't want others to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
import operator
userinput = int(input("enter the number : "))

for operator, sec_operand in {operator.mod: 6, operator.add: userinput, operator.sub: 4}.items() :
    print(operator(userinput, sec_operand))
```